# Using Meta Tags for different Pages in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

I want to use  tags in GWT. I know I could do this in the static index.html file, but I want to add different meta tags on different pages in GWT.

**How can I add meta tag to GWT?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create Meta tags out of GWT:

```
MetaElement element = Document.get().createMetaElement();
element.setName("name");
element.setContent("content");
```

and add it to the head with:

```
NodeList<Element> node = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("head");
Element element2 = (Element) node.getItem(0);
element2.appendChild(element);
```

Something like this should work.

To search for meta-tags, use this:

```
 NodeList<Element> node = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("meta");
 Element element2 = (Element) node.getItem(0);
 String name = element2.getAttribute(name);
```

This will find all meta tags of the document.

Comment: you can remove elements with element.removeFromParent().

Comment: when I do not have an instance of the meta tag Element can I search for them?

Comment: Shouldn't it be MetaElement instead of Element to find a specific meta tag?

Comment: You can cast the Element to MetaElement: MetaElement metaElement = element.cast();